# Failed to install electron-prebuilt in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, electron, npm-install

I am trying to install electron-prebuilt using [the instruction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prebuilt#installation)

but I failed in all ways.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because of error with SSL certificate if you trust the source you can disable [strict-ssl](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#strict-ssl) option in npm using 
`npm config set strict-ssl false`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have try it npm config set strict-ssl false.
Still same problem

Comment: Try running `npm_config_strict_ssl=false npm i electron-prebuild -g` or find and remove ".electron" folder and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Set npm proxy

a.

```
npm config set proxy "http://internal%5c<username>:<password>@uscdtcpxy.internal.imsglobal.com:8080/"
```

b.

```
npm config set https-proxy "http://internal%5c<username>:<password>@uscdtcpxy.internal.imsglobal.com:8080/"
```

*Replace <username> with ur internal username & <password> with lan password for both of the commands